# Rest API permissions service Shopping cart not working for multiple sellers

Tags: rest, service, paypal, permissions, shopping-cart

I own a website that aims to be a "marketplace"
The site will allow people to act as sellers and buyers and products can be sold on auction style listings that allows bidding or on an immediate purchase type listing.

We are struggling to find which would be the best Paypal solution that would allow 'Buyers' to be able to pay multiple 'sellers' for purchased items placed in the buyers shopping cart.

We have tried Rest API. Permissions Service API operations but it does not quite work the way we need it to.

The way our cart works is this ..When a buyer wins an Item in an auction listing or bought as an instant purchase from seller A then the item will go into the buyers site shopping cart to await payment and then if the buyer purchases another item from another Seller B then that will also go into the buyers shopping cart.
The buyers shopping cart now has Items awaiting payment from multiple Sellers .Seller A. and Seller B but when the buyer tries to pay shopping cart does not work as it will now allow payments to multiple sellers.

We need shopping cart to be able to pay more than one seller at a time.
Can you suggest an alternative please that would allow buyers to make payment to be made to multiple sellers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to integrate with paypal third party shopping cart integration if you are maintaining shopping cart on your website:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/

other way to integrate is to use paypal shopping cart instead of maintaining shopping cart on your website:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/add_to_cart_step_1/